# How to upgrade a standalone Jetty installation on Windows?

Tags: jetty, upgrade

This is somewhat embarrassing, but I'm totally lost when it comes to upgrading from Jetty 9.2 to 9.4. 9.2 was installed two years ago using jetty-9.2.0-setup-package.zip. The file contained commons-deamon and more so that the install could be done using command

```
create-jetty-dist.bat d:\jetty9 Jetty9 80 50001 D:\etc\gateway NO
```

Now I've downloaded the latest version from https://www.eclipse.org/jetty/download.html][1](https://www.eclipse.org/jetty/download.html) - jetty-distribution-9.4.14.v20181114.zip - but, I cannot figure out how to upgrade the installation. Mostly I find docs about Maven and update the POM, but the installation is standalone and no Maven. There is a  [Chapter 36. Upgrading Jetty](https://www.eclipse.org/jetty/documentation/current/upgrading-jetty.html) about upgrading - but still does not help much

All my Google-skills does not help either.

I have not found the guts yet to simply replace the folder

```
D:\jetty9\jetty
```

Maybe I do overthink and the solution is that simple. But still it keeps bugging me that I cannot seem to find an install file for 9.4 like I did for 9.2

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I did overthink - is was almost only to replace the 9.2 distribution folder with the 9.4. But for the service to be reconfigured and also to ensure that all changes from 9.2 to 9.4 was implemented me and my colleague had to do:

- Edit the .bat file that came with the jetty-9.2.0-setup-package to support 9.4
- Off course change the reference for all 9.2 to 9.4 distribution in the script
- 9.2 used "logging", 9.4 uses "console-capture"
- 9.2 used "jetty.port", 9.4 uses "jetty.http.port"
- Copy the 9.4 distribution file to the folder where the .bat-file is to be found in the setup-package
- Then we `sc delete jetty9` the service and ran the script.

In short, that was what we needed to do.